# Classic asp putting string in double quotes

Tags: asp-classic

```
remitclient2 = Replace(remitclient2 ,"class=" Chr(34) & ls & chr(34) ">", "^")
```

i want to replace `class="ls">` with `^`

In classic asp I tried escape sequence too and in above I used `chr(34)`.

> Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ee' Expected ')' /US_Offer_2014/lasttry.asp, line 35 remitclient2 = Replace(remitclient2 ,"class=" Chr(34) & ls & chr(34) ">", "^")

Comment: In classic asp i tried escape sequence too and in above i used chr(34).  Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ee'

Expected ')'

/US_Offer_2014/lasttry.asp, line 35

remitclient2 = Replace(remitclient2 ,"class=" Chr(34) & ls & chr(34) ">", "^")

Comment: Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03ee'

Expected ')'

/US_Offer_2014/lasttry.asp, line 35

remitclient2 = Replace(remitclient2 ,"class=" Chr(34) & ls & chr(34) ">", "^")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
remitclient2 = Replace(remitclient2 ,"class=""ls"">", "^")
```

You can do this quickly and easily by doubling up your quotes in the string. If you need quotes at the start or end of the string just remember to include the outer quote also, like so:

```
"abc""def" - quote in the middle
"""abcdef" - quote at the beginning
"abcdef""" - quote at the end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
remitclient2 = Replace(remitclient2 ,"class=""ls"">", "^")
```

is answer i tried and got

Comment: Is is an acceptable workaround but your originally problem is actually due to poor string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a couple of `&`s:

```
 remitclient2 = Replace(remitclient2 ,"class=" & Chr(34) & ls & chr(34) & ">", "^")
```

Comment: Although `"class=""ls"">"` is a perfectly good workaround this is the actual answer, the OP was not concatenating the string correctly hence the `Microsoft VBScript compilation error`.

Comment: If you describe what the `&` does in your answer and why the compilation error occurs then I'll +1, at the moment the answer is a bit lightweight.